# Pyspark dataframe creadted using jdbc, but when tried to write it to a parquet file in hdfs, throws `year out of range` error

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to do data ingestion from Oracle to Hive DB(hdfs) using Pyspark.

The source table has data row as given:

```
LOAD_TIMESTAMP| OPERATION| COMMIT_TIMESTAMP|KSTOKEY|  LPOLNUM|LSYSTYP| XPOLVSN|          LPOLVSN|     XSTOTYP|            DSTODAT|            DSTOTIM|

2024-01-24 16:23:...|2.0000000000|null| 2007.0000000000|  QX-1123|    BS2|1.0000000000|    ORIGINAL TERM|4.0000000000|1998-04-23 00:00:00|0001-01-01 10:33:44|
```

I have this logic of code to read the data to a spark_df and then to write to a target location in hive hdfs path in parquet format:

```
# Read data from Oracle DB using Spark SQL
oracle_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", source_jdbc_url).option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").option("dbtable", "{}".format(final_select_statement))\
    .option("numPartitions", 20).option("partitionColumn", split_by_column).option("lowerBound", int(lowerbound_value))\
    .option("upperBound", int(upperbound_value)).option("user", source_jdbc_user).option("password", source_jdbc_pass).option("fetchsize", 10000).load()
  
oracle_df.show(20)


# Check if Dataframe is empty
if oracle_df.head(1):
  print("EXECUTING NON EMPTY.")

  # Write data to target HDFS path
  oracle_df.write.mode("overwrite").option("path", "{}/{}/{}".format(target_hdfs_path, schema, table_name)).partitionBy("dt").format("parquet").save()
  
else:
  # Create the target HDFS path including the partition
  target_partitioned_path = os.path.join(target_hdfs_path, schema, table_name, "dt=ingestion")

  empty_schema = oracle_df.schema
  empty_df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=empty_schema) 
  print("EXECUTING EMPTY")

  # Write the empty DataFrame to HDFS
  empty_df.write.mode("overwrite").option("path", target_partitioned_path).format("parquet").save()
```

The data is being read into a spark dataframe as oracle_df. The `oracle_df.show()` displays the data.

But right after that, the spark throws an error as given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Full_Ingestion_AQS.py", line 235, in <module>
    pool.map(ingest_table, chunk)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 253, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 572, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: year is out of range
```

this code is part of def_ingest(table_name) function. This function is called within a pool.map() as given below:

```
# Split the tables into chunks for parallel processing
  chunks = [tables_to_ingest[i:i + int(parallel_jobs)] for i in range(0, len(tables_to_ingest), int(parallel_jobs))]

  # Create a ThreadPool with the desired number of workers
  pool = ThreadPool(processes=int(parallel_jobs))

  # Parallelize the ingestion of tables 
  for chunk in chunks:
    print("executing these tables: {}".format(chunk))
    pool.map(ingest_table, chunk)

  # Close the ThreadPool to release resources
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

I know that the date `0001-01-01 10:33:44` is causing the error. But I want to ignore that in pyspark and ingest these data and write the data to hdfs target path.

Any suggestions is greatly helpful and much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems when writing parquet with timestamps prior to 1900 in AWS Glue 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68891312/problems-when-writing-parquet-with-timestamps-prior-to-1900-in-aws-glue-3-0)

Comment: Since AWS Glue is PySpark based, the answers to the referenced question can fix your issues.

Comment: @Zero Thanks for the response. I tried the suggested, and added the parameters in my spark submit command. But it did not fix the issue.

Comment: are you adding those 4 lines at the start of the code?

Comment: @Zero Does that matter in spark submit command? I was adding it after the other --conf settings I already had mentioned, which is the middle of other parameters.

Comment: You need to set those configs before doing the initial read/write.

Comment: @Zero Yes, that is taken care of. spark summit command is the one that initiates the script file that contains this code.