why spark .take(1) is giving error (year 0 is out of range)?
I have spark df created in AWS Glue with no header and columns with values of '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000' or '0001-01-01-00'.
sample data without header
0001-01-01-00 | 2022-07-09-13.24.60.000000 | yyy
2024-06-01-02 | 0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000 | zzz
i created sample df successfully with below code, and when i tried to add if condition with df.take(1) it is giving me error "year 0 is out of range".

df.spark.read.format("txt").option("delimiter",  "|").option("inferSchema", True).option("header", False).load("")
if len(df.take(1)) >0:
True

Note : i used count to validate empty df check but trying to understand why it is giving error for take().

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69040997/233596. Spark is lazy, so I can see not getting the error (if this is the cause) until the take.

Maybe using '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000' as a date is the problem since it is not recognized as valid date.

If it is the Spark config (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69040997/233596) then just adding this to the config may fix it:
spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite: LEGACY

